# How to CURL Jenkins URL when Jenkins is integrated with OKTA with SAML on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, curl, saml, saml-2.0, okta

I have integrated my Jenkins with Okta using SAML2.0 plugin, I am facing an issue when I try to CURL Jenkins URLs.

Any suggestions on how to curl Jenkins URL with Okta using SAML2.0 plugin

Error: which is expected!
"Authentication required"

[image]

Comment: Are you passing an Access Token?

Comment: I have tested with the below approach, suggest me if you have any approaches:
===================

curl --request GET \
  --url 'http://3.92.52.216:8080/computer/(built-in)/api/json' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <0030J4Isn1**************U8jiSt_HwanqSfB41LRANQN>' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json'